# The Mystery Of Mr. Mason's Murder

Tags: riddle

Mr.Mason was a rich man. He lived in a mansion. One day, at 5:30 PM Mr. Mason was found killed lying down next to his bed. His wife Mrs. Mason called the police. There are 5 people: maid, cook, gardener, wife, and brother.The maid said she was cleaning the stairs. The cook said he was cooking breakfast. The gardener said he was watering the plants. The wife said he was sorting her diamonds. The brother said he was sleeping. Who killed Mr. Mason??

Comment: "The ***wife*** said ***HE*** was sorting ***her*** diamonds"?

Answer (score 8):

It was most likely

> The cook

Because

> The cook gave the reason that he was cooking breakfast, but Mr. Mason was found in the evening. This indicates that the cook believed that the murder occurred in the morning, which would only be known to someone present during the crime. Not reporting it until the corpse was found makes the cook at an accomplice, or the murderer if we assume there is only one criminal.

Comment: Same could apply for the brother who was sleeping

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil He could have been napping -- not still asleep from the night.

Answer (score 3):

Well, It could be

> Mr.Mason's **WIFE**

As,

> She could not digest the fact of her husband sorting *HER*  diamonds and hence murdered him! As hinted by Soha FP - credit goes to her.

Comment: Would be harsh...

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

> The wife

Because:

> Jewelry are usually in the bedroom so if anyone wanted to kill him the wife should have seen them. And also he was a rich guy and the wife get's the Most money if her husband dies so she has good reason.

Answer (score 1):

It must be

> The wife

because:

> The wife said she was sorting her diamonds. Most people keep their jewelry in their bedroom, the bedroom that she and Mr. Mason shared. If the wife was sorting her diamonds, she was in the same room as Mr. Mason when he died.

Comment: As per the OP statements, ...The wife said **he** was sorting her diamonds. Not she (the wife) !

Answer (score 1):

> The cook because...
>  she said she was cooking breakfast, suggesting she thought the murder was in the morning (you dont eat breakfast in the evening.) He was not found till the evening. Why wouldn't she tell anyone in the morning??? Because it was her who did it, most likely.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Spoiler tags can be a little fiddly. You need the >! on each line. You can also start a new line by ending a line with <space><space>.